# Live account synced with Windows 8 Laptop and selling it - how to remove everything?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I've setup my live account to work with Windows 8 syncning e-mails and facebook conversations. I'm now selling it and I want to not only remove this account and not render the laptop unusable, but also remove all of the e-mails and conversations that Windows has locally stored. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most laptops come with either a factory restore option or with re-installation disks.

In the case of reinstallation disks:

- Make sure you have all the data you want to keep.
- Wipe the whole hardddisk. E.g. use [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/). Or boot from the DVD and do a full format (NOT a quick format) of the drive. For anybody but the NSA that will wipe all information.
- Then reinstall the base OS so you can show the laptop works when you sell it.

I am assuming the buyer will do his or her own re-installation since you must be pretty trusting to use an OS which some third party installed for you. So do not bother with installing any programs or updates.

---

In the case of a factory reset option:

Well, this sort of depends on how they did it. Some laptops present this option as a program, some need a special button pressed at startup (e.g. Lenovo). The way your laptop does it should be described in the manual.

Comment: This works, but I must also wonder - without formatting can you ever break this inheritance / remove the stored data? Seems like there are scenarios where that could come up.

Comment: You could manually check each folder on the disk and remove it all, but most people are likely to either miss a few locations or remove to much.  Windows 8 also has the options to do a 'reset', but I never used those and I am loath to recommend them without any personal experience. (With reset I mean this option: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kXC60.png )

Comment: Do you know where these store their files? Google is giving m a TON of junk when trying to find out (too many articles about oulook, etc')

Answer (score 2):

Unlike previous Windows, Windows 8 can reset by itself.

To reset your PC

1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, and then tap Change PC settings. (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, click Settings, and then click Change PC settings.)
2. Under PC settings, tap or click General.
3. Under Remove everything and reinstall Windows , tap or click Get started.
4. Follow the instructions on the screen.

Instructions taken from Windows website: [How to restore, refresh, or reset your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-SG/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc)